# Where to find EMF artifact in Maven repository

Tags: maven-2, build, eclipse-emf

We are developing with EMF outside Eclipse therefore using Maven for build. My question is where can I find EMF artifacts, and if yes which version.

BTW Is there any tool to automatically cross-publish Eclipse artifacts with sources to Maven repository?

Renat

Answer (score 2):

You must install/deploy them manually. I use this command line:

```
mvn eclipse:make-artifacts -DstripQualifier=true -DeclipseDir=.../eclipse
```

to get the artifacts into the local M2 repo.

After that, I run [this script](http://blog.pdark.de/2009/10/08/attaching-sources-to-eclipse-artifacts/) to move the source JARs to the right place for Maven to pick them up.

The easiest way to deploy them is to use [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or a similar Maven cache/proxy and copy the files in the right place.

Comment: Will source JAR files also be created?

Comment: Yes but only if you have them. Usually, you can get them by downloading all available "SDKs"

Answer (score 1):

I've patched maven-eclipse-plugin with proper handling of sources (it automatically uploads *.source-* plugins as a sources artifact) and I have added two additional properties:

- -DpomDeps - True (default) generates pom deps based on the OSGi manifest. False otherwise
- -DgroupIds - A comma separated list of groupIds to include. When set it filters out any plugin that doesnt start with any of the comma separated strings. It also provides a way to control the groupId (instead of groupId=org.eclipse.emf and artifactId=core you could have groupId=org.eclipse and artifactId=emf.core when -DgroupIds=org.eclipse)

I still need to submit the patch for it.